# How to add apex class to existing mavens mate project?

Tags: apex, mavensmate

I have an existing project and I need to add an existing apex class. How can I accomplish this in MavensMate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a Mac, go to the MavensMate tab up top -> Metadata -> New Apex Class.

You then select your template and after that there is a prompt to name your file.

EDIT:

Mavensmate -> Edit Project.

Click 'Refresh'on the 'Project Metadata' tab.  Select the missing Apex class and then click 'Update Project'.

Comment: I dont't need to create a new class. I need to add an existing class that is saved in salesforce but is not part of the project.

Comment: This looks like the correct way, however, when I do this the list of apex classes is empty. Any idea?

Comment: @Daniel Try it again.  Sometimes Mavensmate doesn't handle a weak internet connection very well.  Typically if an operation shows up as blank, I just try it several more times until it works.  I run into this issue a lot with running Unit Tests as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click on project folder in the left sidebar. Then select `Manvensmate -> "Refresh from server"`. It will refresh local version with latest server code, which includes your new class also.

Comment: How do I tell mavensmate to refresh that new class?

Comment: By default it will refresh all the classes with latest code in sandbox. You cannot specify for one particular class unless it is imported already to mavensmate. Just give refresh all, anyway other code is already in sync with sandbox right?

Comment: I dont have all the classes in my project so I only selected what I needed.

Comment: oh. Then you have to go by the previous method suggested by dphil